# What does REST API path "/nfsList/{name:.+}" mean?

Tags: api, rest

`name:.+` in the path `/nfsList/{name:.+}` refers to subnet address.

Is `/nfsList/{name:.+}` the same as `/nfsList/{name}`? If not, does `{name:.+}` have some string format checks for subnet address?

Comment: Use the code formatting tags to format your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.+` means any charachter *including* the slash `/`. So `{name:.+}` will capture `foo/bar` in `/nfsList/foo/bar`.

Without `.+`, `{name}` will capture *only* `foo` in `/nfsList/foo`, `/nfsList/foo/bar` will not match this URL.